# Should client create their own JWT

Tags: api, authentication, token, jwt

Is it safe to allow a third party client to create a valid JWT for our resource API? All the examples I've seen require we provide an authentication server for issuing the JWT to authorized clients.

Comment: I think you need understand the difference between resource server and authentication server. If you trust the client, and after they validate the token on your behalf, you can ask them to redirect to callback to your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need understand the difference between resource server (RS) and authorization server (AS).

If you trust the third party client to do the token issuance and validation on your behalf, it is totally fine to delegate the token process to them.

With that said, the flow would be like this:

1. user-agent access your resource endpoint.
2. your security chain check if user has authenticated session, if yes, proceed the request.
3. if not, redirect user to third party authentication endpoint with token.
4. after successfully authenticate the user, callback to resume the resource access.
5. if failed, take the user to access denial page.